# Creating serverless audio processing with Google Cloud Storage and Google Speech to Text

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-speech-api

I'm trying to create a small app that will allow me to translate audio to text via the Google Speech to Text services. I'd like to bypass the need for heavy processing and leverage as many cloud tools as possible to have audio streamed to the text to speech service. I've been able to get the streaming process to work, however, I have to relay the data to my server first and this creates an expense I'd like to cut out. There are a few questions that would help solve my problem in a cost effective way!

1. Can I created a signed URL for a Google Text To Speech streaming session?
2. Can I leverage the cloud and Cloud Functions to trigger processing by the text to speech service and then retrieve real time updates?
3. Can I get a signed URL that links to a copy of the audio streamed to the Google text to speech service?

Comment: I do not think you can create a Signed URL for a Google Text to Speech streaming session. For the second question, what do you mean by leverage if you could be more explicit? For the third question you can get a signed url from Google Cloud Storage and have it in your service.